# How do I remove an element from the Dom in angular 9

Tags: angular

so in my html file I have :

```
<div *ngIf="loading" class="navbar-loading"></div>
```

In my component file I have :

```
public loading: Subject<boolean> = new  BehaviorSubject(true);

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loading.next(false);
}
```

when the page has finished, my div is still in the page and I receive no console error.

if I change the above to:

```
public loading: boolean = true;

public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.loading = false;
}
```

then the div appears to go, but I then get a console error of :

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
> has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current
> value: 'false'

What do  I need to do to remove the div when loading has finished and not receive the console error. I need this for automation testing purposes.

Comment: Why are you setting the variable to false in ngAfterView event?

Comment: @VimalPatel because I want to know when my component has finished loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change anything in `ngAfterViewInit`.

If you really have to, you can use `ChangeDetectorRef` to notify angular that you are aware that something has changed, which will make the error go away.

```
constructor(private  cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

public ngAfterViewInit() 
{
  this.loading.next(false);
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

If you are using observables, you also need to use the `async` pipe

```
<div *ngIf="loading | async" class="navbar-loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use async pipe as loading is an observable.

```
<div *ngIf="loading | async" class="navbar-loading"></div>
```